# Rank per Row values in php

Tags: php

Is there a way to rank this row of multiple values from mysql using php

```
row1- (A,B,C) |  (100,200,39)
row2- (A,B,C)  |  (467,29,89)
```

and wanting the results to look like this

```
  row1
      rank
  A - 2nd
  B - 1st
  C - 3rd

  row2
      rank
  A  - 1st
  B  - 3rd
  C  - 2nd
```

Please any ideas as to how to do this? Thanks

Comment: Use a third array with "1st", "2nd", etc... title, and then use `array_multisort` tagging the title array along the score array. Then, another `array_multisort` to order back the "A B C" array

Comment: what did you try already?

Comment: `arsort($array, SORT_NUMERIC);` This will sort the array values from high to low. After that it's a simple matter of looping through it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the array of the mysql looks like this:

```
$array1=array('A'=>100, 'B'=>200, 'C'=>39);
$array2=array('A'=>467, 'B'=>29, 'C'=>89);
```

Use [arsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php):

```
arsort($array1);
arsort($array2);
```

The second parameter is: **sort_flags**

Which uses these [types](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php):

> SORT_REGULAR - compare items normally (don't change types)
>
> SORT_NUMERIC - compare items numerically
>
> SORT_STRING - compare items as strings
>
> SORT_LOCALE_STRING - compare items as strings, based on the current
>   locale. It uses the locale, which can be changed using setlocale()
>
> SORT_NATURAL - compare items as strings using "natural ordering" like
>   natsort()
>
> SORT_FLAG_CASE - can be combined (bitwise OR) with SORT_STRING or
>   SORT_NATURAL to sort strings case-insensitively

So you could use `arsort($array1,SORT_NUMERIC);`

After sorting it, you can loop through it like this:

```
$x=1;
foreach ($array1 as $key => $val) {
    echo $key.' - '.$x;
    $x++;
}
```